# Sporadic per user Session Data Lost in IIS 6 before Session Timeout, would like some solution

Tags: asp.net, iis, session

I have 2 IIS Servers using IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003. We are using a "round robin" approach to network balancing. A user that gets one server will stay there. 
We are using InProc state management. 
Our Session Time out is 120 minutes too allow for some form pages where entering in the required data may take more than 90 minutes.
Here is what's occurring:
In some cases a user will lose session while working on a page that's been open anywhere from 2 minutes to 60 minutes. Other times session is kept just fine.
We can see that session is lost because a collection of objects is set back to null as well as the integer we use to track which section of our website the user is currently using.

I have read up on the three built in State Servers available and even switched one of our servers to use a local state server which actually increased the number of errors we received.

Additionally we are getting this same issue on our QA server which is IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008.

Please note this is sporadic. A particular user will have this happen while other users sessions are just fine.

Any help or information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your sessions are timing out could be due to the application pool reaching it's idle timeout threshold or the pool could be restarting due to errors or because it's reached it's recycle interval.

I'd consider switching to using the out of process SQL Session State manager if you expect users to be sitting staring at a single page for longer than normal amounts of time. Using the SQL Session State manager will also ensure that your user's sessions survive over accidental or otherwise `IISRESET`'s and pool restarts/recycling.